# Ant Design: How to remove trailing end gutter on each Row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, responsive-design, antd

I am using antd's Row and Col components to create a responsive grid. However, when a column wraps underneath due to a breakpoint, there is some clear whitespace (pretty sure caused by gutters) at the end of the line above a shown bellow: [image: 1]

The textfields belong in one row, and the button in another. There is a gutter next to each text field that I want to get rid of so they properly fit the parent's width.

How would I go about doing that? Quick demonstration:

```py
<Row>
  <Col xs={{span: 24}}>
    <Row>
      <Col xs={{span: 24}} ...>
        <Input/>
      </Col>
      <Col xs={{span: 24}} ...>
        <Input/>
      </Col>
      <Col xs={{span: 24}} ...>
        <DateRangerPicker/>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Col>
  <Col xs={{span: 24}}>
    <Button/>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide the exact source code of your implementation to debug the issue.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

It has gutter attribute, but btw it is 0 by default!